# create-react-app dynamic theme styling path with tree shaking

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have an application created by create-react-app. I would like to import different css stylings for different themes. My styling folder structure looks like `assets/styles/${theme}/style.css`. I would like to pass the theme through the build command as `REACT_APP_THEME=my_theme npm run build`.

However, using dynamic import such as require or import(), I can not take advantage of the webpack tree shaking feature. Before using create-react-app, I was using webpack alias for configuring theme.

So my question is there is a way besides eject that I can configure my theme while still taking advantage of tree shaking.

Thank you.

Comment: `assets/styles/${process.env.REACT_APP_THEME}/style.css`

Comment: Yes, but I can only use require or dynamic import with path like that. Webpack's tree shaking won't work in that case

Comment: set "side-effects": false in package.json and you need to notify webpack of files with side-effects. "side-effects": ["name-of-file.js"]